# RUBY do loop and if statements not executing correctly

Tags: ruby, loops

I am a novice Ruby coder completing a homework exercise related to building LOOPs. The RSPEC criteria for the problem are shown below.  I have tried a number approaches.

I have been able to pass the first two conditions but am totally stuck on how to match and transform just the english articles (a, an, the).  It doesn't appear that I am correctly looping and using the if then construct correctly within the method.

Can you suggest ideas that I can approach to solve this or if there is a simple syntax issue that I am missing?

```
describe "Title" do   describe "fix" do
  it "capitalizes the first letter of each word" do       
    expect( Title.new("the great gatsby").fix ).to eq("The Great Gatsby")
  end     

  it "works for words with mixed cases" do       
    expect( Title.new("liTTle reD Riding hOOD").fix ).to eq("Little Red Riding Hood")
  end

  it "downcases articles" do
    expect( Title.new("The lord of the rings").fix ).to eq("The Lord of the Rings")
    expect( Title.new("The sword And The stone").fix ).to eq("The Sword and the Stone")
    expect( Title.new("the portrait of a lady").fix ).to eq("The Portrait of a Lady")
  end

  it "works for strings with all uppercase characters" do
    expect( Title.new("THE SWORD AND THE STONE").fix ).to eq("The Sword and the Stone")
  end
end
```

Here is the code that I have come up with so far:

```
class Title 
  def initialize(book)     
    @book=book  
  end   

  def fix   
    #create an array of articles    
    art = ['a','an','the']       
    #reformat any string to all lower case to reset to a common format
    @book.downcase.split(' ').map {|w| w.capitalize }.join(' ')      
    #resplit the oll lower case string into an array
    arr = @book.split(' ')      
    #for each element of the array check if in art array if tru
    arr.each_with_index do |element, index|        
      if art.include?(element) then element.downcase
      elsif index == 1 then element.upcase 
      else element.upcase  
      end
    end
    arr.join(' ')       
  end   
end
```

Here are the error messages that I am receiving:

```
•   RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
 expected: "The Great Gatsby"      got: ["the", "great", "gatsby"]  (compared using ==)  
exercise_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
•    Title fix works for words with mixed cases
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
 expected: "Little Red Riding Hood"      got: ["liTTle", "reD", "Riding", "hOOD"]  (compared using ==)  
exercise_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
•    Title fix downcases articles
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
 expected: "The Lord of the Rings"      got: ["The", "lord", "of", "the", "rings"]  (compared using ==)  
exercise_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
•    Title fix works for strings with all uppercase characters
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
 expected: "The Sword and the Stone"      got: ["THE", "SWORD", "AND", "THE", "STONE"]  (compared using ==)  
exercise_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: There are places in your code where you are calculating something but not catching it in a variable, so the statement has no effect. One is `@book.downcase.split(' ').map...`.  Another is if `art.include?(element) then element.downcase`. If `art.include?(element)` is `true`, `element` is not changed. You'd need `element = element...` or `downcase!`. Also, modifying a block variable that you are iterating on is generally a no-no.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here.

1. In a lot of places you do not assign your variables.. For example, `element.upcase`, does NOT assign `element.upcase` to `element`. For that you need to say `element = element.upcase`, or `element.upcase!`
2. Speaking of `upcase`.. `upcase` is for capitalizing the entire word, you want to use `capitalize` (or `capitalize!`)
3. Ruby arrays are zero indexed, so when checking for the first word you want to use index == 0
4. The order of your if/else's isn't quite right. Right now for the first word you check if its an article (and if it is you don't capitalize). It will never check if that its the first word after that.
5. You're missing 'and' in the articles array

Answer (score 0):

The loop is executing correctly, just I think you wrote simply not that you wished. Let's have a book:

```
@book
# => "a The b"
```

You should reformat to lower case just with the simple way:

```
arr = @book.downcase.split(/\s+/)
# => ['a', 'the', 'b']
```

To generate the new modified array use `#map` method:

```
arr.map.with_index do |element, index|        
  art.include?(element) && element || element.capitalize
end.join(' ')

# => "A the B"
```